# Select parent model with child model attribute and destroy it - sequelize/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have `User` and `VerifyToken` model with `token` and `user_id` attributes.
I need to select an user, but with `token` (from `tokens` table) value.

I have tried:

```
 await models.User.destroy({
    hierarchy: true,

   where: {
    token: token
   }
});
```

This is User model:

```
const VerifyToken = require('./verifyToken');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    tableName: 'users',
    //syncOnAssociation: true
    hierarchy: true
});

User.associate = function (models) {
    const {VerifyToken} = models;

    User.hasOne(VerifyToken, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
};

return User;
};
```

And `VerifyToken` model:

```
const User = require('./user');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const VerifyToken = sequelize.define('VerifyToken', {

    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    token: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    tableName: 'verify_tokens',
    syncOnAssociation: true,
    hierarchy: true
});


  VerifyToken.associations = function (models) {
    const {User} = models;

    VerifyToken.belongsTo(User);
   };

    return VerifyToken;
};
```

The problem is that, I even don't know where to start. I have tried with `include:[{model: models.VerifyToken, where: {}}]`, but how to use `user_id` called from the child model ?

What I want is to select an user (parent model) with a value (token in child model) and delete it with one query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement you want is to support `join` and `delete` in one sequelize operation.

> What I want is to select an user (parent model) with a value (token in child model) and delete it with one query.

In sequelize documenation, [Model.destroy](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-destroy) has no `include` in the `options` property.

So the only left option is to select the `user_id`'s from `VerifyToken` model, then call destroy on `User` model, where `id` in `user_id` got from `VerifyToken`.

In code it will look like following

```
const verifyTokens = await VerifyToken.findAll({
   where: {
       token: {
           [Sequelize.Op.In] : YOUR_TOKENS_FOR_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_DELETE_YOUR_USER
       }
   }
}

const userIdsToDestroy = verifyTokens.map(verifyToken => verifyToken.user_id)
await User.destroy({
    where: {
        id: {
            [Sequelize.Op.in] : userIdsToDestroy
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, thx, but if there is a way to select parent with a child column, like in raw query, why I can't call destroy() on it ? Also, I want to delete rows in both tables, but I guess, it will be cascade, because the User is the parent model.

Comment: "but if there is a way to select parent with a child column, like in raw query, why I can't call destroy() on it ? Also, I want to delete rows in both tables, but I guess, it will be cascade, because the User is the parent model." Please make separate question for these queries. @gdfgdfg